# What is a reason of placing boolean or null before comparison operator?

Tags: php

In PHP, what is an underlying reason of placing either boolean or null before identical comparison operator?

```
false === $value;   
null === $value;
```

It seems to me that it is same as saying

```
$value === false;
```

Is it just a personal preference or there is a concrete reason why people do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: He isn't asking what some operator does, he's asking why one would do Yoda comparisons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a convention to avoid the mistake of accidentally assigning a variable.

```
$value = false;
```

instead of

```
$value === false;
```

Comment: +1 , It's important to know the reason! If by mistake you write `false = $value` you'll get an error or warning , unlike `$value = false` which will make you accidentally assigning a variable.(as @nalply wrote)

Comment: @OfirBaruch: I get this argument, I really do... but I still find it less then convincing. The majority of people write their conditions the other way around. When adopting this style, you might find yourself chasing bugs caused by `if ($false === $value)` which is an easy one to overlook. Also, when working in a team, this is the kind of code that many will change, to fit their habits... making `git blame` a bit pointless sometimes. +1 for this answer, though: it's a good point

Comment: It's just a convention. I rarely use it. It feels awkward to me. For me it makes more sense in special cases like in `if (false === ($file = fopen("example.txt", "r"))) die("FAIL");` or such.

Comment: There's no right or wrong , it's just about what's comfortable for you and your code.

Answer (score 4):

This is sometimes referred to as *Yoda-conditions*, there's a fun [list of all such constructs](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html) and their unofficial names.

No there's no real difference between `$var === false` or `false === $var`, some people claim it's easier to see what is being checked for if the bool is the left operand, other hate it... In short: personal preference is what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is useful to know the terms when searching answers online.

Answer (score -1):

It's supposed to be quicker, but I can't lay a hand on an authority saying this with a simple Google search.  See:

http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/222939-is-there-a-difference-between-ifvar-false-and-iffalse-var/

for one opinion.

Comment: I'm not trying to be trollish, but I don't see much point in writing a summary of someone's opinion.

I tested his opinion, and he's right, but only at scale; say, 1-1.5 seconds in 100M operations.  See http://pastebin.com/XsQ8ypPS

Comment: Oh, and let's mark an answer down, then ask for clarification, and then erase our question.  Not nice.

Comment: That's me. I realized that it is impossible to write a summary of this forum. That's why I removed the request to write the summary. Then I donwvoted your answer because I think it is not helpful for StackOverflow to link to a forum. Please read the FAQ why it is not helpful.